# Minus the value of option to itself on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to update the value of selectbox option after click. It should subtract the selected value to itself.

```
    <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

    <label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
    <select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
     </select>
    </div>
<div class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:standardRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK
                                      </span></a></div>
```

**standardRoom function**

```
    function standardRoom()
  {
     $('#selectBoxStandard option').val(Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val()) - Number($("#selectBoxStandard option").val()));
  }
```

If the selected value is **3** after click the remaining value should update to:

```
    <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

    <label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
    <select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please explain more about your expected output

Comment: @Justcode if the option selected is 1 it should subtract one to seven and the option values should stop at 6. because one minus seven is six. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: what if user selects 1?

Comment: @Justcode it would remove one option. Then the option values should only be 1-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove last childs from `#selectBoxStandard` based on `option` value:

```js
$('button').on('click', standardRoom);

function standardRoom() {
  $('#selectBoxStandard').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxStandard').val() + ")").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

  <label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
  <select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
  <button>Update</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but it still update the value after the button click when I select another option. It should just change every time I click the button

Comment: I don't see any button in your code. I added one in the snippet if an update on a button click event is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will work but could probably be done a bit easier or better:

```
function standardRoom(){
    var last_option = $('#selectBoxStandard option:last-child').val();
    var selected_option = $('#selectBoxStandard').val();
    $("#selectBoxStandard option").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() > (last_option - selected_option)){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is working but, it does not auto update the value after click.

Comment: It should be after click it will update the option value

Comment: The value will more than likely disappear.  If you select 5, 7-5 = 2 which means no 5 is able to be selected

Comment: If you want the value you can create a hidden input and change the value so it is stored.

Comment: I mean why is the value change as soon as I select it? Not after I click the button.

Comment: That's what it looked like you asked from the question. If you are looking to create a system that remembers how many rooms have already been booked, you'll more than likely need to store values in DB and run checks.

Comment: You also don;t have a button in the HTML you supplied.

Comment: Ops I just noticed that now. My bad

Comment: Added the button, sorry for the confusion, It should change after the click of the button

Comment: No problem, updated my code to reflect the changes but you should consider @SLePort answer it's very clean

Answer (score 1):

add this js

```
let total = 7
function changed(){
    let selBox = document.getElementById('selectBoxStandard');
    let value = selBox.value;
    //remove all options
    while(selBox.children.length > 0) selBox.removeChild(selBox.children[0]);
    //add new options according to value;
    for(let i = 0;i<7-value+1;i++){
        selBox.innerHTML += `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>` 
    }
    //resets value
    selBox.value = value;
}
```

add onchange on ur select

```
<select onchange="changed()"  required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms">
```

if you want to change on btn click use this

```
<div onclick="changed()" class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:standardRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK
                                      </span></a></div>
```

Comment: Added the button, sorry for the confusion, It should change after the click of the button